# Сount non-numeric values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to count the number of non-int values in a list?
I counted all the elements like this and I don't understand what condition to prescribe.

```
list = [1, 2, "s1", 3, "s2", "s3"]
def number_of_elements(list):
    count = 0
    for element in list:
        count += 1
    return count
print("Number of elements: ", number_of_elements(list))
```

Comment: Let's not use Python built-in *list* as the variable name, maybe lst or others are better.

Comment: Yea i did it differently, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```py
lst = [1, 2, "s1", 3, "s2", "s3"]


def number_of_elements(lst):
    count = 0
    for element in lst:
        if not isinstance(element, int):
            count += 1
    return count


print("Number of elements: ", number_of_elements(lst))
```

Another option is:

```py
def number_of_elements(lst):
    return sum(not isinstance(element, int) for element in lst)
```

If you are checking against all numbers, you can use [`numbers.Number`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#numbers.Number).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sum(isinstance(l, str) for l in lst)
```

Output:`3`